# Removing a response from cURL

Tags: php, curl

I've been messing with a cURL function I made for a couple of days now (mainly trying to find out how I could disable its response whilst keeping it functional). I was trying to find out which echo'd what, and I started adding random variables to echo out to see which returned something while I found this out:

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)');
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Trim("authenticity_token={$Token}&question[question_text]={$Q}&question[force_anonymous]=&authenticity_token={$Token}"));
$Result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
```

See "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER" is set to true? The code fails, and doesn't execute anything.

If I try this:

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, False);
```

It works almost perfectly, except it returns what I don't need returned.

So I tried this:

```
$Test = curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
// after the rest of the code
Echo $Test; // it returns 1
```

and if I remove the echo, it returns nothing and works perfectly.

however, if I remove it completely, it works but still returns what I don't need.

I'm confused as to why it works as I want when it's set as a variable, but when I remove it, it's just like setting it to false?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Never header about this before. I'll suggest you to make a small php file that only does this curl, and then upload every single characters from that script into your question. So that we know you are passing exact information to us!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which part you want me to do, since all 3 of them return different results, but I did test them, and the output is either 1 for keeping RETURNTRANSFER false, "You are being redirected." for removing it completely, or it's empty (which is the one where I assign the variable to it.) I've also never heard of a situation like this, it's extremely puzzling. I mean, it works, so I'm not really complaining, but I'm still very curious as to how assigning a variable to it is causing it to work as I wanted it too.

Comment: That's why I requested to write a `small piece`(may be 10/20 lines) of curl code in a php file(that describes this scenario). Then upload the whole content of that php file(including `<?php` tags) into your answer description, If you really want to know an answer(otherwise forget this).

Comment: Ah, nevermind. What was happening was the boolean value was 1, right? The variable didn't get read, but the default for it is 0, and somehow during script execution changed over to 1 (I'm thinking because I was resetting the variable to define something else which happened to be 1). I removed headers, and other options, so now it's all okay. Thanks for the help though, if it wasn't for you mentioning to rewrite the code in a separate file, I probably would've never realized the duplicated variables.